# How do these nested lambda functions work?

Tags: python, function, lambda

What does this code do? And what are some of the appropriate n, f, and x?

```
def successor(n):
    return lambda f: lambda x: f(n(f)(x))
```

Comment: Its not remotely clear what you're trying to do here. Could you please include some examples of expected input and output?

Comment: What part of the code isn't clear? Have you got examples of how it is used, and the output produced? Without a little more context, the question is too broad for Stack Overflow, really.

Comment: Seems Church Numerals are related to Church Encoding: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding

Answer (score 2):

So this... is pretty bad code.  You shouldn't write it, because as you have found (and the comment section indicates) it is very, very hard to tell what is happening.  Lets break it down.

The original code looks like this

```
def successor(n):
    return lambda f: lambda x: f(n(f)(x))
```

The function `successor` is returning an [anonymous function](http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/lambda_functions.html) using lambda.  That is hard to read, so lets replace it with a named function.

```
def successor(n):
    def inner_function_one(f):
        return lambda x: f(n(f)(x))
    return inner_function_one
```

This is still pretty hard to read.  Lets replace the other anonymous function with a named function.

```
def successor(n):
    def inner_function_one(f):
        def inner_function_two(x):
            return f(n(f)(x))
        return inner_function_two
    return inner_function_one
```

So now we've broken apart the function, and we can see that `successor` returns a function that in turn returns another function, which returns... that.  The line `f(n(f)(x))` is pretty hard to read.  It is saying that a function f is being called with the argument `n(f)(x)`, which is a way of saying that `n(f)` returns a function that is then being passed the argument `x`.  Lets use some more descriptive variable names to see what is happening here.

```
def successor(first_function):
    def inner_function_one(second_function):
        def inner_function_two(arg):
            return second_function(first_function(second_function)(arg))
            # Equivalent to something like
            #     return second_function(returned_function(arg))
            # where returned_function is the result of 
            #     first_function(second_function)
        return inner_function_two
    return inner_function_one
```

As for what is specifically happening here?  I have no idea.  You'd have to ask whoever wrote the code.  However, I'd guess that this is intended to be a decorator of some kind.  There is a somewhat similar example [here](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=240845)

```
def decoratorFunctionWithArguments(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    def wrap(f):
        print "Inside wrap()"
        def wrapped_f(*args):
            print "Inside wrapped_f()"
            print "Decorator arguments:", arg1, arg2, arg3
            f(*args)
            print "After f(*args)"
        return wrapped_f
    return wrap
```

This allows you to use arguments passed to a decorator to be used inside the actual decorator of the function.  That is calling the following function

```
@decoratorFunctionWithArguments(1, 2, 3)
def my_function():
    print "Inner function"
```

would have an output of

```
Inside wrap()
Inside wrapped_f()
Decorator arguments: 1 2 3
Inner function
After f(*args)
```

Thus, appropriate values of `f`, `n`, and `x` are:

```
f : function
n : function that returns a function when passed a function
x : anything that the result of n being passed f accepts
```